# Backbonejs and including jQueryUI components

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, backbone.js

i was asking how to integrate jquery ui components inside backbonejs. and also other jquery libraries like 'chosen'.

as i add for example the datepicker as default and its not working, in a rendered view from backbone.

how to integerate jqueryui in backbonejs.

thanks for the provided comments.

based on the below comments, i add the jqueryui components code to backbone.js view and its working fine now also the timepicker addon.
 the library based on jquery "chosen http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/" which still didn't work with backbone.js views.

Comment: Posting some code may help.  It's hard to figure out what you need without an example.

Comment: I've not had any problems integrating jquery UI with my backbone views.  I normally just create the widgets in the render method.  Can you give an example of what isn't working?

Comment: I agree with both Pope and Tim.  Can you show some more context to what you are doing that isn't working?  I've never had a problem using JQuery in the Backbone Views.  For that matter, the views have a `$` function that allows you to do jQuery directly on the `el` of the view (assuming you are referencing jQuery).  So what, exactly have you tried and what errors are you getting?

Comment: thanks for the provided comments.

based on the below comments, i add the jqueryui components code to backbone.js view and its working fine now also the timepicker addon. the library based on jquery "chosen http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/" which still didn't work with backbone.js views.

Answer (score 0):

I use a trigger at the end of the render method to fire the jqueryui methods. Something like this perhaps.

```
initialize: function () {
    this.on('postRender', this.postRender, this);
}

render: function () {
    this.setElement(document.createElement('div'));
    this.$el.text('click me');
    $('body').append(this.$el);
    this.trigger('postRender');
}

postRender: function() {
    this.$el.button();
}
```

You can trigger 'postRender' when you know that the element is has been added to the dom and is visible, you shouldn't have any problems using it in this way.